# How to create a language model with 2 different heads in huggingface?

Tags: machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I know I can create a language model with 1 head:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForMultipleChoice
model = AutoModelForMultipleChoice.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-cased").to(device)
```

But how can I create the same base model structure (e.g., distilbert-base-cased) with 2 heads? Say, one is `AutoModelForMultipleChoice` and the second is `AutoModelForSequenceClassification`. I need the only difference between the 2 models (1 head vs 2 heads) to be the additional head (from parameters perspective).

So now my input for the 2 heads model is something like `[sequence_label, multiple_choice_labels]`

Answer (score 1):

In general case you will need to create a custom class derived from the `DistilBertPreTrainedModel`. Inside `__init__()` you will need to define your desired heads architectures.  Then you will need to create your own `forward()` function and define inside it a custom loss involving both heads, and return result.

But if you are talking specifically about `DistilBertForMultipleChoice` and `DistilBertForSequenceClassification`, there is a shortcut, as the heads architecture happen to be identical (see [source](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/distilbert/modeling_distilbert.py#L1019)) and the difference is only in loss function. So you can try to train your model as multi label sequence classification problem, where the label per sequence will be `[sequence_label, multiple_choice_label_0, multiple_choice_label_1, ...]` . For example, in case you have an entry like {sequence, choice0, choice1, seq_label:True, correct_choice:0}
your dataset will be

```
[ {'text':(sequence, choice0), 'label':(1 1 0)},  
  {'text':(sequence, choice1), 'label':(1 0 0)} ]
```

This way the result of the sequence classification will be in the first position and to get the correct choice probability you will need to apply softmax function on the rest of the logits.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this! Still trying to figure out how to write the custom class. If you have a previous example or something that would help a lot! Not entirely sure why I need to specify the loss though

Comment: Regarding the shortcut, I like it a lot! One issue is that not the same sequence goes into the 2 heads. To be more precise, for MCQA with 4 answers there is 1 sequence that goes into the `DistilBertForMultipleChoice` 4 times (1 for each answer). But for the `DistilBertForSequenceClassification` I have a vary number of sequences (imagine that I'm splitting the original sequence into sentences not knowing how many sentences are in a sequence). Then, for each of the sequence split I have a label

Comment: So my full input looks more like `[[sequence_label_1, ..., sequence_label_x ], [multiple_choice_label_1,...multiple_choice_label_4]]`

Comment: Regarding examples of the custom class: there is no better then to look at the original code (see link in the answer). Look at the differences of the DistilBertForMultipleChoice and DistilBertForSequenceClassification implementations.

Comment: As for second and third questions: when solving multi label sequence classification problem, you have a predefined amount of classes, and you get a a probability of the sequence to belong to each class. For example in 3 class  problem {good, bad, ugly}, your label will look like [1, 0, 0]. In your setting you will need to add to it another 4 labels for choice. So for  every entry your label will be a vector of size 7. If you split your original sequence to (say) 5 parts, you will send to the model 5 entries where text will be (`subsequence`, <sep>, `choice`) and label will be vector of size 7